# jQuery UI - Spinner with hours not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I took the time spinner example http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time and tried changing it for just hours. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/URgAb/) is my code.

```
jquery.widget( "jQuery.myspinner", jQuery.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
       step: 60 * 60 * 1000
    },

    _parse: function( value ) {
      if ( typeof value === "string" ) {
        // already a timestamp
        if ( Number( value ) == value ) {
          return Number( value );
        }
          return +Globalize.parseDate( value, "hh" );
      }
      return value;
    },

    _format: function( value ) {
      return Globalize.format( new Date(value), "hh" );
    }
});

var myspin = function(){
   jQuery("#spinner").myspinner();
}
```

It is behaving very funny. It increments between 08 and 06 (even though the starting value is 01). Also if I put a break point on line 18, the value in 'value' is 3600000 (probably because step is that) and doubles every time I hit continue. That will increment the value in the input field correctly. But without the breakpoint it only toggles between 08 and 06. If this question sounds confusing, that is exactly what is happening. I am very confused how spinner works.

Note I ultimately want to get the timezone option working (zzz) from  https://github.com/jquery/globalize#dates

Any help is really appreciated